# Different method of Saving in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon! Newbie here so please bear with me :) My question is..

I have 3 worksheets in my Excel workbook. Is it possible to save my 1st worksheet as "SaveAs" only while the 2nd and 3rd worksheets may be saved as "SAVE"? Also is it possible that the 2nd and 3rd worksheets may not be saved unless the 1st worksheet has already been SAVED AS?? Or, is it possible that the 2nd and 3rd worksheet is disabled until the 1st worksheet has already been saved as SavedAs.

i currently have the following worksheets:

BCR 1ST = 1st worksheet

BCR 2ND = 2nd worksheet

BCR 3RD = 3rd worksheet

TIA

Comment: S.A.: It's impossible, it doesn't make sense. Why not to create 2 different documents instead?

Comment: ok, i thought it would be possible using vba code.

Comment: If it helps and it may give you and idea to begin with, you may do a copy of the first sheet everytime the workbook opens and then delete it everytime the workbook closes, so that way you could have the sheet working in a clean template everytime and the 2nd and 3rd will be saved

Comment: I can not do that, as sheet 2 or BCR 2ND picks up values encoded from BCR 1ST and so as BCR 3RD from BCR 2ND :)

Comment: And a copy of it wouldn't make it? No clue how to help then, good luck!